# rostime module not found

Tags: rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I ran rosbridge, it gives me:

```
ros@ubuntu:~$ rosrun rosbridge rosbridge.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/brown_remotelab/rosbridge/bin/rosbridge.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ROSProxy import ROSProxy
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/brown_remotelab/rosbridge/bin/ROSProxy/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ROSProxy import ROSProxy
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/brown_remotelab/rosbridge/bin/ROSProxy/ROSProxy.py", line 6, in <module>
    import roslib.rostime
ImportError: No module named rostime
```

I installed the rosbridge as a fuerte version: sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-brown-remotelab. Since it is updated. why do I still have this problem? Also, I tried to run:

```
svn co http://brown-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/experimental/rosbridge rosbridge
```

it says:

```
svn: 'rosbridge' is already a working copy for a different URL
```

so what should I do? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38295/rostime-module-not-found/) by [shuo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2772/shuo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2012-07-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-09**:
What URL does `svn info` report?

**Comment by [shuo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2772/shuo/) on 2012-07-11**:
Hi, joq, thanks! Problem solved already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Shuo,

This problem is caused by a change in ROS between electric and fuerte.  The rostime module was moved from roslib to rospy.  Thus, when importing roslib.rostime, we now get an ImportError

We have implemented a fix for this and it has been checked into the experimental version of rosbridge.  As you mentioned in your post, you can check this out using

```
svn co http://brown-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/experimental/rosbridge rosbridge
```

With regard to your svn error, I think you might be trying to SVN checkout into a folder that is already under SVN version control.  Please try checking out experimental rosbridge into a fresh folder.

Finally, since you will probably have multiple rosbridge packages on your ROS package path, do a quick check to make sure that the experimental rosbridge is the first rosbridge that ROS finds.  (Just roscd rosbridge and make sure that takes you to the folder that you just created)

This should fix your problem.

Cheers,
Jon

---

Originally posted by [Jon Mace](https://answers.ros.org/users/1507/jon-mace/) with karma: 431 on 2012-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vlonge](https://answers.ros.org/users/31097/vlonge/) on 2017-07-10**:
In that case, could you please change the rosbag.bag documentation to reflect this change? This has been confusing me for a long time.